# Must a ViewModel class inherit from ViewModel() in Android Jetpack?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I'm learning Android Jetpack, the following Code is from a sample project at https://github.com/android/sunflower .

In my mind, a ViewModel classs must inherit from `ViewModel()` in Code B, just like Code E.

1： Why doesn't the class `PlantAndGardenPlantingsViewModel` inherit from ViewModel() in Code B?

2： And more, it seems that the app need launch `executePendingBindings()` opeartion  (Code D,  see [source code](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/adapters/PlantAdapter.kt)) to update `list_item_garden_planting.xml` UI when it use Code B, right?

BTW, the other ViewModel class in the project is inherit from ViewModel(), such as Code E, you can see [source code](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/viewmodels/PlantDetailViewModel.kt).

**Code A**

list_item_garden_planting.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="android.view.View.OnClickListener"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.viewmodels.PlantAndGardenPlantingsViewModel"/>
    </data>
     ...
```

**Code B**

PlantAndGardenPlantingsViewModel.kt

```
class PlantAndGardenPlantingsViewModel(plantings: PlantAndGardenPlantings) {
    private val plant = checkNotNull(plantings.plant)
    private val gardenPlanting = plantings.gardenPlantings[0]
...
```

**Code D**

```
 ...
  fun bind(plantings: PlantAndGardenPlantings) {
        with(binding) {
            viewModel = PlantAndGardenPlantingsViewModel(plantings)
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
  ...
```

**Code E**

```
class PlantDetailViewModel(
    plantRepository: PlantRepository,
    private val gardenPlantingRepository: GardenPlantingRepository,
    private val plantId: String
) : ViewModel() {

    val isPlanted = gardenPlantingRepository.isPlanted(plantId)
    val plant = plantRepository.getPlant(plantId)

    fun addPlantToGarden() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            gardenPlantingRepository.createGardenPlanting(plantId)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Viewmodels are used, when you want to make sure, that there is only one instance in the current context to use, but basically you can bind any class as a viewmodel to a view

Comment: @DominikWuttke, "Viewmodels are used, when you want to make sure, that there is only one instance in the current context to use". This is not always true, it depends on which key you use to store ViewModel. If you get the instance of a specific ViewModel using this as different fragments you get different instances of that ViewModel class.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is not anything magical with ViewModel class. It's creation, and retention which makes it useful.

ViewModel source code simplified

```
public abstract class ViewModel {
    // Can't use ConcurrentHashMap, because it can lose values on old apis (see b/37042460)
    @Nullable
    private final Map<String, Object> mBagOfTags = new HashMap<>();
    private volatile boolean mCleared = false;

    /**
     * This method will be called when this ViewModel is no longer used and will be destroyed.
     * <p>
     * It is useful when ViewModel observes some data and you need to clear this subscription to
     * prevent a leak of this ViewModel.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
    protected void onCleared() {
    }

    @MainThread
    final void clear() {
        mCleared = true;
        // Since clear() is final, this method is still called on mock objects
        // and in those cases, mBagOfTags is null. It'll always be empty though
        // because setTagIfAbsent and getTag are not final so we can skip
        // clearing it
        if (mBagOfTags != null) {
            synchronized (mBagOfTags) {
                for (Object value : mBagOfTags.values()) {
                    // see comment for the similar call in setTagIfAbsent
                    closeWithRuntimeException(value);
                }
            }
        }
        onCleared();
    }
}
```

Which is a container where you call onCleared() when you are done with it. 2 things that make a ViewModel class is useful are

1- You get the same ViewModel if you use the same Activity(key of hashMap)
2- You get the same ViewModel after device rotation

If you check out the super classes of `AppCompatActivity`, you can see that `ComponentActivity` class implements the`ViewModelStoreOwner` interface.

This interface has a method `getViewModelStore()` which creates or returns a ViewModelStore item.

```
public ViewModelStore getViewModelStore() {
            if (getApplication() == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Your activity is not yet attached to the "
                        + "Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.");
            }
            if (mViewModelStore == null) {
                NonConfigurationInstances nc =
                        (NonConfigurationInstances) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
                if (nc != null) {
                    // Restore the ViewModelStore from NonConfigurationInstances
                    mViewModelStore = nc.viewModelStore;
                }
                if (mViewModelStore == null) {
                    mViewModelStore = new ViewModelStore();
                }
            }
            return mViewModelStore;
        }
```

and ViewModelStore is container for a HashMap that holds keys as class names.

```
public class ViewModelStore {

    private final HashMap<String, ViewModel> mMap = new HashMap<>();

    final void put(String key, ViewModel viewModel) {
        ViewModel oldViewModel = mMap.put(key, viewModel);
        if (oldViewModel != null) {
            oldViewModel.onCleared();
        }
    }

    final ViewModel get(String key) {
        return mMap.get(key);
    }

    Set<String> keys() {
        return new HashSet<>(mMap.keySet());
    }

    /**
     *  Clears internal storage and notifies ViewModels that they are no longer used.
     */
    public final void clear() {
        for (ViewModel vm : mMap.values()) {
            vm.clear();
        }
        mMap.clear();
    }
}
```

If you use the same objects to retrieve a ViewModel, if key has equals and hashcode, you get the same ViewModel.

That's how you get **same** `ViewModel` in fragments if you use `Activity` as key

mvViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(activity!!, viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

2- You get the same ViewModel after device rotation since ComponentActivity class has a method

```
  /**
     * Retain all appropriate non-config state.  You can NOT
     * override this yourself!  Use a {@link androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel} if you want to
     * retain your own non config state.
     */
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public final Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        Object custom = onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance();

        ViewModelStore viewModelStore = mViewModelStore;
        if (viewModelStore == null) {
            // No one called getViewModelStore(), so see if there was an existing
            // ViewModelStore from our last NonConfigurationInstance
            NonConfigurationInstances nc =
                    (NonConfigurationInstances) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            if (nc != null) {
                viewModelStore = nc.viewModelStore;
            }
        }

        if (viewModelStore == null && custom == null) {
            return null;
        }

        NonConfigurationInstances nci = new NonConfigurationInstances();
        nci.custom = custom;
        nci.viewModelStore = viewModelStore;
        return nci;
    }
```

If you wish to benefit from these two features you can use Jetpack `ViewModel` or you can build same structure using a HashMap and factory pattern for creation of a custom ViewModel class implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Based your answer, only "2 things that make a ViewModel class is useful " ,  does it mean most of case I don't need use a class inherited from ViewModel() ?

Comment: And in most databinding solution, I only need a normal class for layout databinding, right?

Comment: Those two features are very useful, you don't handle to get same instance for different fragments, it's onCleared method gets called when Activity is destroyed and same instance is returned when device is rotated. Those features are pretty great if you ask me but you can implement those yourself if you wish.

Comment: Data-binding does not require you to have a ViewModel, you can do it with MVP, MVI, or any other architecture you wish. For databinding you need to enable data-binding in gradle, create a layout with <layout> tag and set lifecycle of data-binding if you wish to use it with LiveData, but ViewModel class is not required.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.
So,in some cases,you shouldn't inherit from ViewModel() when Activity/Fragment is killed and re-built the view-model will be reused, the same instance of view-model. For example, local(country or language) of the device has been changed, the Activity might be destroyed and recreated, the view-model will be still the one like before-destroy.
Besides,you can see more detail in this link.https://github.com/android/sunflower/issues/132